Ros2 canopen io slaves and cia402 slaves on the same bus
Is it posible to have a io slave and 2 cía402 slaves driver on the same bus wit ros2 canpen?. I would like to connect some field sensors to the io slave and control a differential robot vía cia402 drivers. I have only seen cía301 system or cia402 system but not a mix of them.
